# How to redirect user to a specific page after they login if they belong to a certain role?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

We have certain users in our member list that have a role "vendor" attached to them. All such members are to be redirected to a certain page upon login. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Warning! Redirecting users after log in can have strange and definitely unwanted effects! http://drupal.org/node/1772880

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define actions and triggers in Drupal:

Action(**admin/settings/actions**)
- *Redirect to a specific page*

Trigger (**admin/build/trigger/user**)
- *After user has logged in*

Try this.

### EDIT (see comments):

Create a small module to check on a user's login process what role he has and then redirect if neccesary.
[drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_goto) => redirect-function in drupal

[hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_user) =>triggers on user operations

And for the user's roles:

```
GLOBAL $user;
$roles = $user->roles;
$vendor = in_array('vendor', $roles);
```

$vendor then holds a true/false value will decide to redirect or not.

If you don't know how to do this, just post here and I'll write the module for you. But this would be a good practice for writing future drupa modules for you perhaps. :)

Comment: That's going to redirect all users, not ones with a specific role.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read the question properly, my bad.

You can create a small module then and use hook_user with $op = login, check the user's role and then do a redirect perhaps?

Answer (score 11):

There is more than one way to skin this cat...
This is my preferred Drupal 7 method:

```
function hook_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  $edit['redirect'] = 'node/123';
}
```

Comment: This works for "node paths". How would you redirect to a custom menu action?

Comment: In exactly the same way: $edit['redirect'] = 'my_custom_menu_item';

Comment: Why the downvote? Please elaborate if there is anything wrong with this! As far as I'm aware this is the correct and most "Drupal" method of achieving this...

Answer (score 6):

For Drupal 7

Action --> **admin/config/system/actions - Redirect to URL**

then enable your trigger module

Trigger  --> **/admin/structure/trigger/node**

if your are  trying to login redirect just follow this(select user tab in the page)

go to --> **admin/structure/trigger/user**

then 
**Trigger: After a user has logged in**

choose an action -->***Redirect to URL*** and assign.

Then clear the cache.

It will work for you!

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways in DRUPAL 7

1) Using action and trigger 
see this http://drupal.org/node/298506

2)if using custom module

```
function YOURMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {

 if (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset' || variable_get('login_destination_immediate_redirect', FALSE)) {

 if(in_array('THE-ROLE-WANTED-TO-REDIRECT',$account->roles)): 

drupal_goto('PATH');

 else: drupal_goto('user/'.$account->uid); 

endif; 

} 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

Events: User has logged in.
Condition: User has role
Actions: Page redirect

Answer (score 2):

There are modules that do this (besides Trigger+Actions), such as LoginDestination: http://drupal.org/project/login_destination.  This [Drupal forum post](http://drupal.org/node/160854) has a bit more info about it as well.

Answer (score 2):

following condition for hook_user

```
if($op =='login') drupal_goto("your path");
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using a combination of [content access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) and [login toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) modules. You'll be able to restrict pages and prompt user to login to access them.

Answer (score 1):

First set the conditions in form preprocess (for example I want to redirect only users that logged in using the form at node page)

```
function YOURMODULE_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    $pathArguments = explode('/', current_path());
    if (count($pathArguments) == 2 && $pathArguments[0] === 'node' && is_numeric($pathArguments[1])) {
        $form_state['nodepath'] = current_path();
    }

}
```

than define redirect:

```
function YOURMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{
    if (isset($edit['nodepath']) && !empty($edit['nodepath'])) {
        drupal_goto($edit['nodepath']);
    }
}
```