# Drupal: redirecting users with specific role to another page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I redirect only users **with a specific role** to the admin page when they login ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to redirect user to a specific page after they login if they belong to a certain role?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429767/how-to-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-after-they-login-if-they-belong-to-a-cert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to get the global `$user` variable. And then check if the user has the desired role, (in this case I assumed the desired role is '`authenticated user`'), and the current page is not the admin page (so you don't get a redirection problem), then redirect him to the admin page, or a page of your choice inside `drupal_goto('admin');`

There you go:

```
<?php
    global $user;
    if(in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles) && arg(0) != 'admin') {
      drupal_goto('admin');
    }
?>
```

Comment: this works but I highly recommend using the Login Destination module instead: http://drupal.org/project/login_destination