# Redirect authenticated Drupal user to iFrame containing Drupal website

Tags: redirect, iframe, drupal-7, audio-streaming, persistent

I am working on a web radio website based on Drupal 7. To ensure a persistent audio experience the HTML5 radio player needs to be in an iFrame so that the music will not stop every time the page reloads (i.e. when the user navigates the page). Using Ajax for navigation is not an option because the js will conflict with other js already in the site.

So what I want to do is redirect the user after login to load the whole iFrame (containing the Drupal website and the HTML5 web player).

Unauthenticated User -> www.domain.com/index.php (just the Drupal site)

Authenticated User -> www.domain.com/iframe.php (Drupal site + HTML5 player)

I want the HTML5 player to be visible only to authenticated users.

I did try this advice: [How to redirect user to a specific page after they login if they belong to a certain role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429767/how-to-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-after-they-login-if-they-belong-to-a-certain) role?

This did not work. Possibly because my iFrame is not made by Drupal?
Neither did various redirect modules:

https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect

https://www.drupal.org/project/url_redirect

https://www.drupal.org/project/front

https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect

None of my tests worked out. The closest was the front module. Unfortunately, it added another player upon each page reload so that after 12-14 reloads the entire screen is full of players.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check if user logged in or not and then decide to redirect user to a different pages, use `user_is_logged_in()` function to detect user logged in status and then using `drupal_goto()` function redirect the user to the url that you want.